# Raising a negative number to an odd negative fractional exponent

Tags: exponential-function

Perhaps I am overthinking this but $(-4)^{(-5/2)}$ is not a valid equation, am I correct? Working through the problem gives me $1/(-4^{5/2})$ which then works out to $1/\sqrt{-4^5}$ which leaves a negative number in the square root, which is not valid.

Comment: To avoid another long discussion, you should re-write the expression as (-4)^(-5/2),   Assuming you want to raise negative 4 to a power

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly valid, the result is simply not a Real Number, it is what is called an Imaginary Number (or a Complex Number in the case in which you had a Real Numbered component as well), which you may not be familiar with.

The result you gave simplifies down to $-\frac{1}{32}i$, where $i$ is called the Imaginary Unit, and is equal to $\sqrt{-1}$.

If you cared to investigate this further try reading these for a decent introduction: [Complex Numbers on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) and [Imaginary Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number). Khan Academy also has a good [video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/imaginary_complex_precalc/i_precalc/v/introduction-to-i-and-imaginary-numbers) on this subject for the introductory level.

Comment: Okay thanks, I should clarify with my instructor as to whether or not he expects real numbers in my calculus 1 course, as my pre-calculus teacher lead me to believe that we will not be using imaginary numbers until calc 3.

Comment: One usually deals briefly with complex numbers sometime in one's Algebra 2 or Pre-Calculus career. Calculus at the high school level never involves Complex Numbers to my knowledge, that is usually saved for what is called Complex Analysis.

Answer (score 0):

The square root of a negative number is a complex number. $(-4)^{-{5/2}} = {1 \over (\sqrt{-4})^5} = {1 \over (2i)^5}=-\frac{1}{32} i$. If this sounds like complete gibberish to you, google "imaginary numbers" and read up on it.